# Jquery Click show hide button using if for css

Tags: jquery, click, hide, show

I have been trying to make a button that toggles the visibility of another div... here is the JavaScript i am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var navwidth = $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width');

    $('div#showhidenav').click(function () {
        if ( navwidth == "0px" ) {
          $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width', '850px');
        } 
        else if ( navwidth == "850px" ) {
          $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width', '0px');
        }
    });
});
```

And it does work, at leas for the first click, but the second time i click on the button, it is supposed to do the opposite, to ether again show or hide the div. But nothing happens.

So to be clear, it works for the first click but not for any next

Comment: Why not just use jquery `.toggle()`?

Comment: @JacobTomlinson becasue i need to have a sliding transition

Comment: `.toggle()` has transitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are using a stored value(on DOMReady) and you do not update it, therefore only of the condition blocks is executed,  `css` method accepts a function, you can use this function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showhidenav').click(function () {
        $('#navigationpanel').css('max-width', function(i, m){
            return m === '850px' ? '0px' : '850px';  
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on()`

```
$('div#showhidenav').on('click',function () {
    var navwidth = $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width');
    if ( navwidth == "0px" ) {
      $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width', '850px');
    } 
    else if ( navwidth == "850px" ) {
      $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width', '0px');
    }
});
```

put `navwidth` inside click event call.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variable on page load and not updating it when you modify the div. To fix this you could check the value instead of using a variable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#showhidenav').click(function () {
        if ( $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width') == "0px" ) {
          $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width', '850px');
        } 
        else if ( $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width') == "850px" ) {
          $('div#navigationpanel').css('max-width', '0px');
        }
    });
});
```

But if you are just wanting to show and hide the div jQuery has a built in function called `.toggle()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showhidenav').click(function () {
          $('#navigationpanel').toggle();
    });
});
```

For a transition you can specify duration and easing. From jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> .toggle( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
>
> ```
> duration (default: 400)
> Type: Number or String
> A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> easing (default: swing)
> Type: String
> A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
>
> complete
> Type: Function()
> A function to call once the animation is complete.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `tag#id` selectors, just `#id`, the former makes it slower
2. Cache your target object
3. Use `.on()` for event listening
4. Use `.slideToggle()`

CSS:

```
#navigationpanel {
    max-width: 850px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $nav = $('#navigationpanel');

    $('#showhidenav').on('click', function () { $nav.slideToggle(); });
});
```